# Memory leakage in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am taking a class on c++ for which I need to write a simple program that leaks memory on purpose. I have tried this by creating `new char []` and not deleting them, but this does not seem to work. Below is the complete code I have tried.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    while (i<1000){
        char *data = new char [100000000];
        *data = 15;

        i++;
    }
}
```

When I watch the memory usage of the program it does not grow so it is not leaking any memory. I just get a bad allocation error.

Comment: Please define *"does not seem to work"*

Comment: check your process memory. It will increases with loop continue

Comment: When I watch the memory usage of the program it does not grow so it is not leaking any memory. I just get a bad allocation error.

Comment: @RobSchneider Memory allocation is happening faster than you can watch on your Process manager... So, you end up allocating 0 or more ~100MB chunks of memory until memory allocation fails. This happens much faster than you can see. Add a `std::cerr` and probably a [`std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) in your loop

Comment: Allocate a lot more a lot smaller blocks. Ten million blocks of 100 bytes each should illustrate the problem nicely.

Comment: @n.m. It either runs instantly or crashes my computer.

Comment: What is the message when it crashes? What is your environment (Linux, Windows, Mac, ...)?

Comment: If it crashes your computer you probably need a better OS. Can't really help with that. In which case does it run instantly? Are you building a 32 or a 64 bit executable? Do you actually touch memory you allocate?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest case of memory leakage is dynamically creating an object then immediately losing the reference to it. In this short example, you are immediately losing a reference to the variable you've created, causing the memory leak. Memory leaks in small, contrived programs like these make it hard to appreciate memory leaks because as soon as a program exits, the operating system reclaims the memory the program allocated.

The problem becomes serious when the program runs for long periods of time. The memory leak is exacerbated and computer performance is noticeable hampered.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// Object is being created, allocated on the heap then function immediately exits, losing any reference to the object. This is a memory leak
void createObject()
{
    int* x = new int;
}

int prompt()
{
    int response;    
    std::cout << "Run again?\n";
    std::cin >> response;

    return response;
}
int main()
{
    while(continue)
    {
        createObject();

        // Running the program again and again will exacerbate the memory leak.
        continue = prompt();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Correct way to retain object reference in this contrived and useless example:

```
int* createObject()
{
    int* x = new int;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    // Pointer to the object created in the function in this scope is created, so we still have access to the variable.
    int* a = createObject();

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps, good luck in your class!

Answer (score 0):

If you put some delay in the loop, you will be able to see the memory grow.
You can use sleep or wait for input from the user.

As it is now, the memory inflate so fast till you run out of allocation memory.

This is not a classic test of memory leak.
Memory leak it tested at the end of the program to see if you released all the memory.